# Is there an R function which removes an element of a list and stores all elements in another list

Tags: r, combinations, permutation

I have 3 data sets in a list and I want to build a model using all combinations of test and training data. For example:

- Model 1 : Train data - 1,2, Test data - 3
- Model 2 : Train data - 1,3, Test data - 2
- Model 3 : Train data - 2,3, Test data - 1

The approach I am using right now is laborious and not smart. Here is an example and my question is, how can I automate this procedure?

```
Day1 <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3))
Day2 <- data.frame(x = c(4,5,6))
Day3 <- data.frame(x = c(7,8,9))

Days <- list(Day1,Day2,Day3)

Test <- list()
Train <- list()

Train[[1]] <- bind_rows(Day1, Day2)
Test[[1]] <- Day3
Train[[2]] <- bind_rows(Day1,Day3)
Test[[2]] <- Day2
Train[[3]] <- bind_rows(Day2,Day3)
Test[[3]] <- Day1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `combn` to create all the combination of indices and then use `lapply` to select those elements for `Train` and remove those elements from `Test`.

```
train_inds <- combn(seq_along(Days), 2, simplify = FALSE)
Train <- lapply(train_inds, function(x) dplyr::bind_rows(Days[x]))
Test <- lapply(train_inds, function(x) dplyr::bind_rows(Days[-x]))
```

Check the output

```
Train
#[[1]]
#  x
#1 1
#2 2
#3 3
#4 4
#5 5
#6 6

#[[2]]
#  x
#1 1
#2 2
#3 3
#4 7
#5 8
#6 9

#[[3]]
#  x
#1 4
#2 5
#3 6
#4 7
#5 8
#6 9

Test
#[[1]]
#  x
#1 7
#2 8
#3 9

#[[2]]
#  x
#1 4
#2 5
#3 6

#[[3]]
#  x
#1 1
#2 2
#3 3
```

Comment: Thank you. You originally used sapply for the test list but now you have changed it to lapply. Any reason why? Both give the same answer but with lapply, your structure will be a list within a list.

Comment: @Ali If you always have only one dataframe in `Test` (as in this example) `sapply` should be fine. However, if there could be more than one dataframes in `Test` in that case you need to use `lapply` with `bind_rows`.